# Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON' - MS SQL Server - possibility of being unable to solve the issue

Tags: sql-server, database, authentication, kerberos

Why not asking on dba.stackexchange: the description says it is for professionals, which I am not and SO has its "for enthusiasts" part.

I have an error
"Login failed for user 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON'"

This is a common error with several possible reasons and solutions. The problem is that I have no knowledge of the database and server administration and credentials authentication topics, thus I will need to spend some significant time understanding what is being said and proposed.
Before I do that I would like to ask if it might be possible for me not to be able to solve the problem due to technical limitations. I will describe the situation in more detail now.

There is an MS SQL Server A with database Adb and table dbo.At. I can read from it. There is also an MS SQL Server B. I can read and write here.

I have MS SQL Server Management Studio 2012 open on my computer. I have a connection with server A open with query "select * from Adb.dbo.At" which works just fine. The connection used Windows Authentication.
I have a connection with server B (Windows Authentication as well) with query "select * from A.Adb.dbo.At" which results in the aforementioned error.

At this point I do have read access to A, I have read and write access to B. I can export data from A and then import it to B using my computer, i.e. I can do a kind of a copy paste and I will end up having what I want. There is no insurmountable wall between these 2 servers with me being the middle man. I simply would like to make it easier. Before I dwell on SPNs, delegations, Kerberos, Active Directory and whatnot I would like to ask if, assuming that I have nothing more than read on A and read/write on B, I might not be able to solve the issue?

Comment: at which point you got this error?

Comment: When I execute "select * from A.Adb.dbo.At" from the level of connection to server B.

Comment: I think server B already added as a linked server to server A. So, try to look into linked servers of server A (Object Explorer -> Server Objects -> Linked Server -> Server B-> properties-> security) . you might have needed to debug the login issues from there

Comment: Can you execute an `OPENROWSET` query like the following ?: SELECT a.* FROM OPENROWSET('SQLNCLI', 'Server=A;Trusted_Connection=yes;', 'select * from Adb.dbo.A') AS a;

Comment: SQL Server blocked access to STATEMENT 'OpenRowset/OpenDatasource' of component 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' because this component is turned off as part of the security configuration for this server. A system administrator can enable the use of 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' by using sp_configure. For more information about enabling 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', search for 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries' in SQL Server Books Online.

Answer (score 1):

It seems I have a "double hop" problem.

https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askds/2008/06/13/understanding-kerberos-double-hop/

I have found a workaround. I can use Server Agent on server B. Using this I can use the server to perform some actions, for example query other servers. The Agent jobs are of a specific type (like T-SQL script). For specific job types the Agent can run the jobs in "run as" mode (requires a proxy). I created a proxy referring to my normal Windows login. Sadly T-SQL script type job cannot be executed in "run as" mode. But PowerShell type job can. PowerShell can also execute SQL statements. Thus I have created PowerShell job running with proxy with the command being:

```
SQLCMD -Q "select * into Bdb.dbo.Bt from A.dbA.dbo.At" -E
```

This solved my problem.